# Como definir uma tag vazia no XML com Delphi?

Tags: delphi, xml

Desenvolvi um sistema, ainda em Delphi 6, para Medicina do Trabalho, sei que tenho que atualizar, mas é impossível fazer isso agora.

Meu problema é com a criação de uma arquivo XML para exportar dados para e-social.

Estou usando a seguinte rotina para criar uma tag vazia:

```
exame := Aso; 
exame.AddChild('exame'); 
Aso.ChildNodes['exame'].NodeValue := '';
```

só que o resultado é: `</exame>` 
e preciso que seja: `<exame></exame>` ou seja aberta e fechada.

Comment: E qual o problema em si?

Comment: Junior, obrigado. O problema é que não consigo criar uma tag vazia ou seja sem o espaço em branco, tipo <exame></exame>, utilizando a rotina na minha pergunta.

Comment: Pois bem meu amigo, qual o problema que isso lhe gera? Até onde entendo, não existe problema algum nisso. </nome> é = a <nome></nome>

Comment: Junior obrigado novamente. O problema é que na hora que envio me retorna erro no item exame. Pois no xml que é gerado esta <exame/>. Meu amigo como saio dessa ?

Comment: Júnior na realidade o que ocorre é que na hora de validar o arquivo gerado não passa é da erro justamente aqui </exame> qdo não tem exames complementares. Então como passar a validação ? Desde já muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão para solução imediata do problema é não utilizar o componente do delphi para gerar o xml.

E seu problema não é apenas pela versão do Delphi, aqui, utilizamos a ultima versão e o mesmo problema ocorre.

No caso, pode ser que do outro lado não esteja validando como XML, e sim como um texto puro, procurando tags específicas, abrindo e fechando.

Portanto.

```
var
  vArquivo: TStringList;
begin
  vArquivo := TStringList.Create;
  vArquivo.Add('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="8859-1" ?>');
  vArquivo.Add('<XML>');
  ... outras tags
  vArquivo.Add('<exame>' + VariavelComValor + '</exame>');
  vArquivo.Add('</XML>');
  vArquivo.SaveToFile('Unidade:Caminho\NomeArquivo.xml');
end;
```

Comment: Junior obrigado pela orientação. Realmente não tinha pensado em usar um StringList, estou usando o XMLDocument. Vou refazer a rotina e retorno para você se deu certo ou não. O curioso é que consegui validar quando existem os exames complementares.

Comment: Junior infelizmente não deu certo. Dessa maneira ele não gera um arquivo xml e sim um txt comum. Tem outra alternativa ?

Comment: Negativo meu amigo, o xml é um arquivo de texto puro. Inclusive utilizo este procedimento para comunicar com uma api Soap.

Comment: Ok, entendido. É que não mecho com isso, então a minha dificuldade. Bom a minha dúvida é que tentei abri no internet explorer e apareceu a página embranco. Utilizando o outro modo ele aparecia normalmente. Outra coisa, como fazer a endentação do documento ? Desde já agradeço muito a atenção em me ajudar.

Comment: "no internet explorer e apareceu a página embranco" então você salvou com falha na estrutura. Aqui, abre em qualquer navegador. Inclusive é valido em qualquer validador online.

Comment: Ok. Estou terminando a rotina nova. Posso enviar para você para sua avaliação ?

Comment: Se possível edite sua pergunta, adicione como detalhe.

Comment: Amigo, utilizei o Notepad++ e o arquivo abriu legal, só não estava endentado.

Comment: Fiz tudo certinho, gerou beleza mas na hora de validar da erro de xmlpaserdoc. Estou usando o programa da ACBr, pode ter algo a ver ?